# Inheritance for Bean class in Java

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am working on Jsf2 project with primefaces. I have used some thing like this:
Bean class:

Student Its the main Bean class with id and name. I have created two more bean class. Technical student and non technical student both these are extending student bean class. My question is am I doing Right? Is it right design ? I want to keep id and name common which is reusable across technical student and nontechnical students page

```
class student{
        id, name
        getter and setter
}

class Technicalstudent extends student{
        technicaldetails, 
        get and set
}

class NonTechnicalstudent extends student{
        nontechnicaldetails
        get and set
}
```

Comment: Yes you are doing right. but make sure that your student getter setter should be public.

Comment: @AshishAggarwal: Question came to while creating a front end. In addstudent I am just saying student.name, and I have kept a drop down box to select technical or non technical, based on this value I am creating object of technical or non technical at the back end and storing student name and id and details details in DB, while retrieving from data base again I have to display data respectively on page so there is change I have to do on technical and non technical and show it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your design is correct from inheritance perspective. Subclass/child need to inherit the common properties from parents and they can have their own properties.

Comment: does this still apply if the `Student` class is a `ManagedBean`?

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: I have kept studentBean as backing bean and I am using technical and non technical student backing bean. Student controller as managedbean.. When We do inheritance on bean class  modification has to be done to display on front end. So I got this confusion, is it right way to do this

Comment: @shreekanth, I am not quite sure about the managed bean inheritance thats why asked Juned. I will look into it when I find some time and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I found nothing wrong with the code based on what you want to achieve. What you did here is called [is-a relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). Meaning a TechnicalStudent and a NonTechnicalstudent is also a Student. Therefore it will inherit every fields from Student. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is correct but As on Ui you have to map your enity with backend object. Map object with Student object and take aboolean is student object like `Boolean isTechnicalStudent` and based on the option set it `true` and `false`.
 
On UI end toggle your form of technical and non-technical student details and now due to this boolean you always have a knowledge that wether it is technical or non technical so you can easily type cast.